# Android onSingleTapUp not called for more than one pointer

Tags: android, gesture-recognition

I'm trying to distinguish between a single pointer tap (one finger), to a tap with two pointers (two fingers).
I have noticed that `onSingleTapUp(...)` is called only for `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`,
while `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP` can be recognized only from `onTouchEvent(...)`.
Is there an API method for this case, or I must override `onTouchEvent(...)` and distinguish between those cases with `MotionEvent.getPointerCount(...)`?

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { 

    if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Log.v("GESTURE", "onTouchEvent ACTION_UP");
    }

    if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
        Log.v("GESTURE", "onTouchEvent ACTION_POINTER_UP");
    }
    this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}


public boolean onSingleTapUp (MotionEvent event) {      

    if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Log.v("GESTURE", "onSingleTapUp ACTION_UP");
    }
}
```

Comment: you could check that the MotionEvent.getPointerCount is >1 and if so do whatever math needs to be done differently in a custom onTouchEvent or onSingleTapUp method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
       if(event.getPointerCount() > 1){
       //do some math for the multiple pointers using event.getPointerId() to refer to diff. pointers.
       }else{
            // it's a one-touch event, do regular stuff.
       }
    }
```

Comment: I'm looking for an API method to handle two pointers tap case, rater than override `onTouchEvent`, if their such method

Comment: @user1869297 from what I've gathered from searching about; no there is not. It's not that hard to create your own basic class to control this however.